# Synonomize [veriton]

Tags: discussion, tag-synonym-request

A new [acer-veriton](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/acer-veriton) tag was recently created.  It has a wiki excerpt and a single question.

There was an existing [veriton](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/veriton) tag, with no wiki contents, and three questions after I removed the tag on one where somebody mistook it for a Verizon tag.

Suggest synonomizing [veriton](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/veriton) with [acer-veriton](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/acer-veriton), with the latter as the primary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nevermind.  There were only three questions, all old, with nobody following the tag.  I just went ahead and retagged the questions.